# Microsoft Report Viewer not Displaying R2 features properly

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2008.
I have used the Report Viewer for displaying the reports in web application but all the R2 features are not rendererd properly in (Specially the trend images used).

I have tried to find the root cause:
1. The export functionalty is diplaying images but its not visible in webbrowser.
2. I tried to use the iFrames but simillar results i got.

Q: How i can fix the html content which is rendered but not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the above problem i had to install the newer version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms (v10.0.0.0).

This is a patch provided by microsoft in visual studio 2010 SP1.

Please find the link below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2011/03/31/visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx

Amazingly it solved all of my problems :)